# Update UI with respect to data from observable

Tags: java, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have LiveData in my InfoViewModel (written in Java)

```
public LiveData<List<Info>> getAllInfo(){ return allInfo }
```

In my DashboardActivity (written in Kotlin) i am trying to observe this LiveData then use result from the observer to update a list which should in turn update a portion of my UI.

The portion of my UI to be updated when there is a change in infoList size

```
 if(infoList.isEmpty){ Text("Empty") } else { Text("Info list size is ${InfoList.size} ") }
```

At first i used

```
val infoList by remember { mutableStateOf(ArrayList<Info>)}
SideEffect { infoViewModel.allInfo.observe(activity as LifecycleOwner, { infoList.addAll(it) } ) }
```

But my UI did not update when infoList size was updated by the observer. I searched here on stack overflow and found

```
 observeAsState
```

So i did this

```
 val infoList by infoViewModel.allInfo.observeAsState
```

But then observeAsState show errors. What can i do. My main problem here is notifying that portion of my UI that my infoList has changed and it should update itself or at least any way to update my UI with respect to the observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So... I later discovered that

```
  observeAsState
```

Is part of the

```
  androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata
```

artifacts so i added

```
  implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"
```

to my build.gradle (app level). I also added

```
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

to my build.gradle (app level), converted my DAO, repository and ViewModel classes from Java to Kotlin. After doing all these, i was able to

```
  import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState
```

Then on my DashboardActivity, inside my @Composable function

```
  val context = LocalContext.current

  val infoViewModel: InfoViewModel = viewModel(factory = InfoViewModelFactory(context.applicationContext as Application))
  /*this particular type of viewModel(factory = ...) is available after adding implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha02' to build.gradle (app level)*/

  val infoList = infoViewModel.allInfo.observeAsState(listOf()).value
```

Then the portion of my UI that needed to be updated when there is a change in infoList size

```
  if(infoList.isEmpty){ Text("Empty") } else { Text("Info list size is ${InfoList.size} ") }
```

Started to work perfectly. In essence,

```
  implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"

                                      ...

  import androidx.compose.runtime.livedata.observeAsState

                                          ...

  val infoList = infoViewModel.allInfo.observeAsState(listOf()).value
```

got the job done for me :-)